# Trivial intersection of torsion of a module an annihilator of that torsion

Tags: linear-algebra, modules, torsion-groups

I was studying *Introduction to Module Theory* from the book *Dummit D., Foote R. Abstract algebra (3ed., Wiley, 2004)*. A question related to this topic I got from a friend of mine:

**Let $A$ be an integral domain and $M$ be a finitely generated $A$-module. Denote by $M_{tors}$ the torsion sub-module of $M$ and $I$ be the annihilator of $M_{tors}$. Is it true that $$IM \cap M_{tors}=0?$$**

I tried to prove this by contradiction:

$A\rightarrow I.D.$ & $M\rightarrow A$-module.

$M_{tors}=\{m\in M\colon a.m=0 \text{ for some nonzero } a\in A\}$

$I=\{a\in A\colon a.m=0 \forall m\in M_{tors}\}$

If $IM\cap M_{tors} \ne 0$ then let $m'\in IM\cap M_{tors}$.

So If we take $S=\{m_1,m_2,...,m_n\}$ be the minimal generating set of M then $m'=a_1.m_1+a_2.m_2+...+a_n.m_n$ & $a.m'=0 \forall a\in I$.

Hence we have,$$a.m'=aa_1.m_1+aa_2.m_2+...+aa_n.m_n=0 \forall a\in I$$

Since $A$ is an I.D. if $a \ne 0$ then at least one of the coefficients in the representation of $a.m'$ must be nonzero.

But this cannot be a contradiction.

Then I tried to find example that denies this, but I also failed at that. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: It shouldn't be hard to see that this is true when $A$ is a PID (using the fundamental theorem of finitely generated modules over a PID) or when $M$ is torsion. So if there is a counter example it would need to involve: $A$ being an integral domain but not a PID, and $M$ being nontorsion (not torsion free though). Don't know off the top of my head if there should be such a counter example, just food for thought.

Comment: Yeah, if $M$ is torsion then $I$ became annihilator of $M$. So $IM$ itself became trivial, and so the intersection.

Comment: @Tamas Kanti Garai I think if you have a counterexample over $A$, then you can descend to a counterexample over a finitely generated subring of $A$ (in particular a Noetherian ring).  Specifically, using your notation, let $A'$ be the ring generated $\mathbb{Z}[a,a_1, \ldots, a_n]$ and let $M'$ be the $A'$-module generated by the $m_i$.  Next you can reduce to the local case, because there must be some prime $\mathfrak{p}$ for which $m'$ is nonzero in $M'_\mathfrak{p}$, and because localization commutes with finite intersections and taking torsion submodules.

Comment: So basically you can assume that $A$ is local and Noetherian, if that makes any difference.